# Configure nginx to forward port from 3000 to 80

Tags: nginx, web, portforwarding

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;

    location / { 
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_http_version  1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;
  }
}
```

I have an NodeJS/Express app listening on port 3000. How do I redirect requests to `<ip-address>:3000` to `<ip-address>:80`?

The above configuration did not work. (shows `404 Not Found
nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)` when I go to port 80.)

Comment: Is this one a single file inside folder `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`?

Comment: @LucaT. There's no file inside that. I edited `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Is that the wrong file to edit?

Comment: Well, not properly. Usually a common configuration on linux is to keep as default (which near last line is `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`, i.e. to include every conf inside `conf.d` as part of the configuration) and create a single file for each server in `conf.d`, starting with a `server { ... }` node. My doubt was that you maybe nested 2 http conf once resolved (like `http { http { server { ... }}}`)

Comment: @LucaT. I ran `sudo nginx -t && sudo service nginx reload` which checks if the config is valid so that doesn't seem to be the problem.